# How to solve ● TCPWRAP or ● TCPSERVERWRAP issues with Express and Supertest

Tags: express, testing, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I encountered these ● TCPWRAP or ● TCPSERVERWRAP while trying to run a test on ExpressJs using Supertest.

Jest has detected the following 2 open handles potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

●  TCPWRAP

```
  22 |
  23 |
> 24 | mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL);
     |          ^
  25 |
  26 | mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  27 |   console.log("Connected to MongoDB Successfully");

  at makeConnection (node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connect.ts:398:18)
  at connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connect.ts:52:3)
  at checkServer (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/monitor.ts:305:10)
  at node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/monitor.ts:350:5
  at executeAndReschedule (node_modules/mongodb/src/utils.ts:879:5)
  at makeInterruptibleAsyncInterval (node_modules/mongodb/src/utils.ts:886:5)
  at Monitor.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/monitor.ts:153:54)
  at Server.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/server.ts:241:23)
  at createAndConnectServer (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:803:10)
  at node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:418:9
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Topology.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:416:26)
  at createTopology (node_modules/mongodb/src/operations/connect.ts:98:12)
  at connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/operations/connect.ts:52:10)
  at node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:458:14
  at maybePromise (node_modules/mongodb/src/utils.ts:462:3)
  at MongoClient.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:457:24)
  at node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:809:12
  at NativeConnection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.openUri (node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:798:19)
  at node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:381:10
  at node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
  at promiseOrCallback (node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
  at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1234:10)
  at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose.connect (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:20)
  at Object.connect (index.js:24:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/integration/order.route.test.js:1:21)
```

●  TCPSERVERWRAP

```
  33 | });
  34 |
> 35 | app.listen(PORT, () => {
     |     ^
  36 |   console.log("Listening on port, ", PORT);
  37 | });
  38 |

  at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
  at Object.listen (index.js:35:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/integration/order.route.test.js:1:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is when you import your app into your test and use it, it starts running your server. So you'll need to separate your `app.listen()` method and put it in another file: `server.js`. And you also need to close your connection to the database after running every test or else you would get this `● TCPWRAP`.

So let's see where the errors actually come from and how to solve them.

The `TCPSERVERWRAP` comes from your app running while your test has finished.

```
> 35 | app.listen(PORT, () => {
     |     ^
  36 |   console.log("Listening on port, ", PORT);
  37 | });
```

and TCPWRAP usually came from connecting to MongoDB (in my case, I used mongoose)

```
 > 24 | mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL);
```

**To fix this:**

Make sure you separate your server from your main app like this, so that, `server.js` contains:

```
// server.js
const app = require('./index');

const PORT = 3334;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port, ", PORT);
});
```

and in your main app or `index.js`, as in my case;

```
//app.js or index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello World!");
});

module.exports = app;
```

This will only solve the `TCPSERVERWRAP` issue. To solve the `TCPWRAP` issue, you need to paste this into your test file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

beforeEach(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL);
})

afterEach(async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Make sure you changed the `process.env.DB_URL` to your own database URL.